# Need a single RegEx for 4 similar but different input patterns

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, regex-lookarounds

I want a single regular expression to capture the following 4 inputs:

Input_1: CountryINDIA
O/P: Country, INDIA

Input_2: CountryIndia
O/P: Country, India

Input_3: CountryINDIAAustralia
O/P: Country, INDIA, Australia

Input_4: CountryIndiaAustralia
O/P: Country, India, Australia

I tried the following regex. It worked for input_3 but failed for input_1:
`"(^[A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z]\w.*(?=[A-Z]))?((?<=[A-Z])\w.*$)"`

Input_3: CountryaINDIAAustralia
O/P: [('Country', 'INDIA', 'Australia')] #WORKS!!!
Input_1: CountryINDIA
O/P: ('Country', 'INDI', '') #did not work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex, which captures one of the following:

- `[A-Z][a-z]+` Uppercase letter followed by one or more lowercase letter
- `[A-Z]+(?![a-z])` One or more uppercase letters not followed by a lowercase letter

[See it in use here](https://regex101.com/r/kolKIU/1)

```
(?:[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?![a-z]))
```

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression you have tried is not able to capture Input_1 because it expects the country name to start with a capital letter followed by lowercase letters, and "INDIA" starts with a capital letter. You can modify the regex to handle this case as follows:

```
regex = r"(^[A-Z][a-z]+)|([A-Z][A-Z]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+)"
```

Edited new regex and
Example:

```
import re

test = 'CountryINDIA'
regex = r"(^[A-Z][a-z]+)|([A-Z][A-Z]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+)"

matches = re.findall(regex, test)
# Flatten the list of tuples and remove empty strings
matches = tuple([match for group in matches for match in group if match])
print(matches)

#output
('Country', 'INDIA')
```

Edited again (cuz won't work for this case 'CountryINDIAAustralia').
So u need to special splitter and u don't need anymore regex module for example:

```
def custom_split(s):
    result = []
    current_word = ''
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if i == 0:
            current_word += c
        elif c.isupper():
            if s[i-1].islower() or (i < len(s) - 1 and s[i+1].islower()):
                result.append(current_word)
                current_word = c
            else:
                current_word += c
        else:
            current_word += c
    result.append(current_word)
    return tuple(result)

test = 'CountryINDIAAustralia'

matches = custom_split(test)
print(matches)

#output
('Country', 'INDIA', 'Australia')
```

Comment: This isn't valid in python without an external lib like PyPi. It also doesn't handle cases where country is all uppercased.

Comment: @ctwheels yes you're right i edited now my regex and this is will run correctly and yes you need 'regex' module for use this

Comment: The update provided is better than the original, but does still fail on the input case of `CountryINDIAAustralia`.

Comment: @ctwheels yes you're right i'm looking for solution now

Comment: @ctwheels now everything looks right

Comment: Your non-regex code works well; great alternative to using regex